# Glide not resize image correctly on Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-glide

I use the bumptech [android-glide](/questions/tagged/android-glide) library to show a bottom banner image on my [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) application on two different activities. The problem is the main Activity load the image and shows at full size instead of showing **centered**.

[image]

I override the size in both definitions but I can't resize the image on the first Activity. I think the second one is using the cached image loaded by **glide** but I'm not really sure.

[image]

> Code of image declared on both layout Activities

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/main_sponsor_banner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/default_main_sponsor"/>
```

> Code of glide library on both Activities

```
ImageView sponsorImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_sponsor_banner);
String sponsor_url = "https://static.prosperwalk.com/prosperwalk/organizations/0E79176F-75EB-4096-A1F2-35B886AE24E0/members/FF72A93A-DAB2-4127-ABF2-9417F1F128B7/4D1D86BF-E2A2-4C52-8485-921EDCB7CC99.png";
Glide.with(this)
        .load(sponsor_url)
        .thumbnail(0.5f)
        .crossFade()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.default_main_sponsor)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .into(sponsorImage);
```

Thanks and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE`

Comment: I try to use the four different types of _DiskCacheStrategy_ but the image doesn't change.

Comment: i have the same error now. It's happening because wrong sized image is caching in memory. I found another method, but have not try yet `.skipMemoryCache(true)` It must skip cached data in memory